# Ansible VMware - Any module or method can search a vm folder and return its VM guest list?

Tags: ansible, vmware, ansible-facts

I am working on Ansible automation and need to get the VM list from searching a specific VM folder in vCenter.

As I know there is a module "vcenter_folder.py", it can create or delete a vcenter folder but cannot return information/fact.

Does anyone know how can I get the vm list using Ansible? thank you so much.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do that with Ansible and not through native pyvmomi commands, which Ansible is using under the covers?

Answer (score 2):

here is how to return all vms in a folder :

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
  vars_files:
            - vars.yml
  tasks:
   - name: returning vm list on a folder
     vmware_vm_info:
        validate_certs: no
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_server }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_user  }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
        folder: "datacenter/vm/foldername"
     register: vms
   - debug:
         msg: "{{ vms | json_query('virtual_machines[*].guest_name') }}"
```